# Loop through sub-folder and save to .csv in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have a folder called `Folder` structured like this:

```
Folder/
├── Folder1
│   ├── image1.jpg
│   ├── image2.jpg
│   ├── image3.jpg
│   ├── image4.jpg
│   └── image5.jpg
├── Folder2
│   ├── image1.jpg
│   ├── image2.jpg
│   ├── image3.jpg
│   ├── image4.jpg
│   └── image5.jpg
├── Folder3
│   ├── image1.jpg
│   ├── image2.jpg
│   ├── image3.jpg
│   ├── image4.jpg
│   └── image5.jpg
└── Folder4
    ├── image1.jpg
    ├── image2.jpg
    ├── image3.jpg
    ├── image4.jpg
    └── image5.jpg
```

I have a code that prints the Folders along with the images in each folder.

```py
rootDir = '.'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fname)"
```

However, I want to write a code to loop through the sub-folders and save each of the 5 images to a `.csv` file. For example, if I have participant `1` I want a `.csv` file containing the images from `Folder1` if I have participant `2` I want a `.csv` file containing the images from `Folder2`, and so on.

I think I might need to create an empty list, and then save to a `.csv` file like below:

```py
lst = []

cols = ['participant', 'imagefile']

pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=cols).to_csv('imagefiles.csv', index=False)
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't look like you're going to need `pandas` for this. What is the output you're getting, and the one you'd like ? You can use the function `open("/some/path", "w")` to write into a file.

Comment: Do you want one big `CSV` file with all the information consolidated in? Can you give us a sample of what that `CSV` would look alike?

Comment: @accdias I would like it to save each sub-folder (and 5 images in that folder) to separate .csv files depending on what participant number they have, so there will be one .csv for participant 1, one .csv for participant 2, and so on. I'd like the .csv to have the column labels "participant" and "imagefiles" and under "participant" I'd like 5 rows of '1' and under imagefiles 5 rows containing the images from the folder

    1              image1.jpg
    1              image2.jpg   
    1              image3.jpg            
    1              image4.jpg   
    1              image5.jpg

Comment: You don't need pandas for that. The standard library [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module can handle that just as fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution in Python 3.6+ (3.4+ because of [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), and 3.6+ because of [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)
):

```py
from pathlib import Path
import csv


folder = Path('/path/to/main/Folder'):
csvdir = Path('/path/to/store/csv/files')
participants = [1, 2, 3, 4]
headers = ['participant', 'imagefile']

for participant in participants:
    participant_folder = folder / f'Folder{participant}'

    # Do we have a Folder for participant number? 
    if participant_folder.is_dir():
        # create a csv file in csvdir for participant
        with Path(csvdir / f'imagefiles{participant}.csv').open('w') as f:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(f, quote=csv.QUOTEALL)
            
            cswriter.writerow(headers)

            for image in participant_folder.glob('*.jpg'):
                csvwriter.writerow([participant, image])
```

Comment: [`pathlib` was backported all the way to 2](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/)  -- The link above was meant to be: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Good catch. I fixed the answer, but I will keep Python 2 out of the mix because it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get every jpg file names in subfolders to a csv file.

```
import csv
import os
import glob

root_folder = '/path/to/root_folder'
out_csv_name = '/path/to/out.csv'
dir_list = os.listdir(root_folder)

filename_list = []

for each_dir in dir_list:

    with open(out_csv_name, mode='a') as crop_file_name:

        csvwriter = csv.writer(crop_file_name, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        for image in glob.glob(os.path.join(root_folder,each_dir+"/*.jpg")):

            csvwriter.writerow([os.path.basename(image)])
            filename_list.append(os.path.basename(image))

print(len(filename_list))
```